# How do I change the tcga data barcode rowname?

Tags: r, for-loop, r-rownames

My tcga data's barcode, row name, looks like this.

TCGA-4P-AA8J-01A-11D-A390-01

I want to change it to this form using a for loop.
-> TCGA.4P.AA8J.01A

```
r=c()
for (x in rownames(df)) {
     r <-c(substr(gsub("-",".",x),1,16))
     rownames(df)<-r
     print(r)
   }
```

....?

Comment: Is the process described by delete the 4th dash and everything following and the change the remaining dashes to periods?

Comment: Yes It's the process of trying to do as you say

Answer (score 0):

Both substr and gsub are vectorized so just:

```
rownames(df) <- substr(gsub("-",".",rownames(df)),1,16)
```

No need for loopy iterative construction when all the functions are vectorized.